# Maximum of a curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $k$ dimensional affine space and let $\gamma$ be curve that intersects $V$ in two points $p$ and $q$. Say $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma(1) = q$. Does there always exist a point $r \in \gamma$ such that the normal space of $\gamma$ at $r$, $N_{r}\gamma$, makes an angle of $90^{\circ}$ with $V$?

Reasoning from basic calculus it seems like I can treat $V$ as the "$x$-axis" and $\gamma$ as a function whose domain is in $V$ and whose range is in the normal direction of $V$. Then the maximum of $\gamma$ from $V$ must be a point whose tangent space is parallel with $V$.

Comment: Hint: consider the function $s \mapsto \mathrm{dist}(\gamma(s),V)$.

Comment: Ya, so that's what I did. But past saying "consider the maximum of $s \mapsto d(\gamma(s), V)$, denote $s^{*}$, and notice that at this point  the normal space $\angle(N_{s^*}\gamma,V) = 90^{\circ}$" I don't know what is required to prove it more "formally".

Comment: Let $p\in V$ be the point that is closest to $\gamma(s^*)$, the line segment connecting $p$ to $\gamma(s^*)$ is orthogonal to both $\gamma$ and to $V$. (You can prove this by contradiction.)